# How to manage nested routes and controllers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, controller, routes

We have multiple models Post, Blog, Wiki and Comment.

In the comment table we maintain object_type, object_id and comment_type.

### Comment table data

```
id        object_type      object_id      comment_type
 1        'Post'           1              'System'
 2        'Blog'           2              'System'
 3        'Wiki'           3              'User'
 4        'Wiki'           4              'System'

/post/1/comments/:comment_type
/wiki/1/comments/:comment_type
```

To handle this, How should my routes should look like and how many controller should I create to handle different comment types ?

Comment: which model (Post, Blog, Wiki) would you like to associate the comment with?

Comment: are you looking for routes like `/:object_type/:object_id/comments/:comment_type` and RESTfully handle them as `/:object_type/:object_id/comments/:comment_type/:id` and `/:object_type/:object_id/comments/:comment_type/edit/:id`, etc.?

Comment: @engineersmnky ok. But how can I generate this type of routes ? And how can I handle this requests in controller ? Should I need to generate multiple controllers ?

Comment: Very Good question Kunal.. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent model from the url:

```
before_filter :get_commentable

def create
  @comment = @commentable.comments.create(comment_params)
  respond_with @comment
end

private

def get_commentable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
  @commentable = resource.pluralize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end
```

Comment: How can I generate this type of routes '/:object_type/:object_id/comments/:comment_type/:id' for different models?

Comment: you can generate it custom on routes file. get '/:object_type/:object_id/comments/:id', :to => 'controller_name#action_name' i`m not so sure for url. Can you use restful routes ?

Comment: if your comment_type are only two you can handle it two ways, /wiki/1/comments/user (user is custom action on collection) or with sending params /wiki/1/commnets?type=user

Comment: We have four different type of comments and 7 to 8 models which supports comments.

Comment: maybe with controller that handle all types of commentables and send it as params to index action

Comment: you can check this controlelr https://github.com/Genshin/gaku/blob/enrollmentable/frontend/app/controllers/gaku/enrollments_controller.rb one controlelr that handle all types of resources that have enrollments, in your case you can send params of comment_type and filter inside index. this is only one controller + 2 routes because its used in two resource. But can be added more 7-8 and controller will be still 1

Answer (score 0):

As for this:
/post/1/comments/:comment_type

nesting the resources as in so:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

gives you:

```
post_comment_path    GET     /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)  comments#show
```

you can do the same thing for the other resources.

UPDATE:

about selecting comment_type, for example, one way to handle it is to create a separate model.

```
class Comment
  has_and_belongs_to_many :comment_types
end

class CommentType
  has_and_belongs_to_many :comments
end
```

i you are using simple_form, in your new.html.erb form, you will do this:

```
<%= f.association :comment_types %>
```

this will give you a drop down to select the comment_types. you can create the comment types in your console. say you have only: "system" and "user" comment_types. simply create those in the console and they will both show up in the drop down for you to select.

If you take this approach, you don't need to nest the resources in your routes.rb file.

Comment: ok and how should I handle this inside my controller ? How can I fetch 'object_type', 'object_id' and 'comment_type' in controller ?

Comment: why not just fetch with :id? If for example you fetch comment with id=1, shouldn't that give you all the relevant data associated with that comment? like object_type, object_id and comment_type.

Comment: but lets say while creating how may I know what type of comment should I create and for which object ?

Comment: I'm thinking in your new.html.erb form, you can do select the attributes: object_type and comment_type. not sure yet.

Comment: see the updated answer. let me know if it does make sense to you